# Deserialize Generics over Web API?

Tags: json, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have an object like so:

```
public class Criteria
{
    public List<Param> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

For Param, I have the following:

```
public abstract class Param {}

public class Param<T> : Param
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public T SelectedValue { get; set; }

    public QueryParameter(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Such that when I want to create a Criteria package, I make something like:

```
Criteria newPackage = new Criteria();
Param param1 = new Param<string>("City");
Param param2 = new Param<int>("Population");
newPackage.Parameters.add(param1);
newPackage.Parameters.add(param2);
```

The idea is that a consumer gets this Criteria package, and does this:

```
receivedPackage.Parameters[0].SelectedValue = "New York";
receivedPackage.Parameters[1].SelectedValue = 15820582;

SendBackToWebAPI(receivedPackage);
```

But the Types are not maintained when passed over the Web API.  So I get a message like so:

```
Could not create an instance of type Param. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
```

I have a feeling this is not fixable, but perhaps there is another way to accomplish what I'm doing?

For added clarity: The goal here is that a consumer has no clue what the criteria are.  They want to know something, but to get that information, particular criteria are required.  So I pass a set of criteria they have to fill out, then they fill it out and send it back.  Then I use those criteria parameters to fill in my queries and can then pass back normal objects as usual.

Comment: As your error mentioned abstract classes may not be instantiated. Change it to something like below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073243/implement-common-behaviour-in-alternative-to-abstract-base-classes

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't see how that helps with deserializing generics across `Web API`.